# I want to persist the store to redux with expo AsyncStorage but i get error

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I wanted to persist my store in AsyncStore.I fetch my initialState before i create my store.But it doesn't wait to fetch data and give error "The preloadedState argument passed to createStore has unexpected type of 'Object' ".

this is my loadState function

```
export const _loadState = async () => {
  try {
    const serializedState = await AsyncStorage.getItem('store');
    if (serializedState === null) {
      return undefined;
    }

    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (error) {
    return undefined;
  }
};
```

and this is my store

```
const initialState = _loadState();

const store = createStore(reducers, initialState);
```

I expect promise must resolve before createStore() but it doesn't resolve.
English is not my main language so if there is a place you don't understand let me know.Thank you

Comment: I solved the problem using `redux-thunk`.I realised that i did not follow the principle `The only way to change the state is to emit an action, an object describing what happened.`. When my component mounted i dispatched action to get store from AsyncStorage.

Answer (score 0):

```
const initialState = await _loadState();
```

you can use await to make sure 100% it resolves before it.

use try catch to handle error case here

Comment: i tried the put _loadState() in async function then await _loadState() and return it but it gives new error."Enhancer(createStore) is not a function,enhancer(createStore) is an instance of Promise."

Comment: try to see what's value of typeof state is

Comment: I solved the problem using `redux-thunk`.And state was first 'undefined' then 'object'.